# $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ must be zero?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, operator-theory

Define $f\in V,$  $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $x\mapsto f(x)$

A functional will be looked like $F:V\to\mathbb R$, $f\mapsto F[f]=y$

An operator is $T:V\to V$, $f\mapsto Tf$

In the most accepted notations, does $f(x)\in\mathbb R$ merely a real number?

When we apply an operator on $f(x)$, for example $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=0$ in strict sense?

Comment: It's common to write $f(x)$ both to denote the function $f$ and to denote the value of $f$ at the point $x$; this is an "abuse of notation."

Comment: I'm not sure [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742562/how-to-formalize-a-variable-binding-operator-such-like-fracddx) would help.

Comment: $f$ is a function and $f(x)$ is a number. But it's pretty common to abuse notation by referring to the function as $f(x)$ instead of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you see the ambiguity? Let's use you example. There you are applying an operator. The elements this operator maps are functions (in your case $f$) and NOT reals (like $f(x)$). The value that this operation takes on once applied to a function is a function, that is the derivative of $f$. This latter function maps real (in your case $x$) to real.

Then probably with $\frac{d}{dx}$ you are not meaning the operator that maps differentiable functions to their derivative functions but the functional that takes as inputs a function *and* a point, that is the functional "derivative of a function in a point".
But then such a functional would have been defined as something like so:

$$F: V\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},~ (f, x) \mapsto F[f, x] = F(f, x) = F f (x)$$

where $V$ is the set of real differentiable functions.
So it's only a matter of taste as how to represent the "application" of a functional: using square brackets, parentheses, exponential, postfix, infix, prefix notation, or mixing things up.

Back to your example, if it were a scalar functional that took as input just only one argument, a function, you would not have had ambiguity either because $f(x)$ is a real not a function and it would have been obvious that $f$ was the element to which the functional was to be applied and not $f(x)$. As a consequence $x$ should have been interpreted as a formal parameter, not a value. (Much in the same guise as when a sequence is indicated $\{x_n\}$ and often simply $x_n$ as well, with $n$ a formal parameter, not a specific value)

Answer (score 2):

It's common to write $f(x)$ for both the function itself and as the image of the point $x$ under the function. Whether this is a bad thing and we should always write $f$ for the function itself and never $f(x)$ is a matter of taste. One minor point in favor of allowing the notation $f(x)$ for the function itself is that it reminds you how many arguments the function takes.

Clearly, $ \frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ is $not$ usually intended to mean "the derivative of the constant function whose value is given by the value of $f$ at the point $x$." Depending on the context, it could either refer to the derivative of $f$ (a function) or the value of the derivative of $f$ at the point $x$ (a number).

Maybe it's bad or ambiguous notation. But we're implicitly assuming that the application of $\frac{d}{dx}$ binds tighter than the application of functions, so that what we mean is $$ \left(\frac{d}{dx}f\right)(x).$$

Comment: I think the symbol $\left(\frac{d}{dx}f\right)$ is also weird. For example, define $f$ to be the sine function, what does $\left(\frac{d}{dx}f\right)$, namely $\left(\frac{d}{dx}\sin\right)$ mean? How do we know that $x$ refers to the variable? Have we said it?

Comment: @Eric $\sin:x\mapsto \sin(x)$. sin is just a $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ operator (or C to C).

Comment: @Eric True. Notation is hard. I guess we haven't said it, but we've implied it pretty strongly (and there's pretty much no room for misinterpretation). Ideally from a purist standpoint you have notation for the derivative operator that doesn't have an $x$ in it, say $D$. And in general, I much prefer $f'$ as the notation for $f$'s derivative, anyway. So we have $(Df) = f'$. And then I guess $\sin'$ is much more palatable. And $D\sin$ is less standard but also palatable.